# Insert Data into local db and Remote DB Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, local-storage, remote-server

I have registration form from my local computer and also in remote server.
now my problem is registered using local registration form on my local computer it will be updated on local db and  remote server db. if  registered using remote server it will be automatically update on remote db and  my local db.

how can i do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create a local script that accepts the data from remote server when registration takes place and write them to local db? In other words make a script working like service ($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'] ect) and after a succesful insert responds OK and then the remote script inserts the data. Following this plan you also have to create scripts for update and delete. Also you may add cryptography to your data and security orders to protect the procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1'; //Replace ip with your remote server's Ip
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Please ensure mysql server is installed and running on your remote server.